# Can I get android to generate random objects?

Tags: class, random

I'm making a game. Every "enemy" is represented by a class. So what I want, is to write some code so that android randomly generates knew classes (enemies) every time they get killed. Because I want to be able to control with a variable how many enemies the player has to fight.

I'm writing in Java (Android).

Hopefully I make myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: If the language you're using supports polymorphism, then you can make a base class: `Enemy`, and have each different type of `Enemy` inherit from it.  After that, you can use any random int generator, and decide which type of Enemy you want to make in a `Switch` Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on SamIAm's comment, suppose you have `5` classes of enemies, called `EnemyClass1` through `EnemyClass5`.

Create a random number generator using `java.util.Random`, and then use it to generate an `int` in the range from to 0 to 4.

```
// Somewhere in your program initialization, should run once and only once.
Random random = new Random();

// In the place where you want to generate the enemies.
int choice = random.nexInt(5);
Enemy newEnemy = null;
switch (choice) {
    case 1:
       newEnemy = new EnemyClass1();
       break;
    case 2:
       newEnemy = new EnemyClass2();
       break;
    case 3:
       newEnemy = new EnemyClass3();
       break;
     // etc

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But my question really came down to: How can I generate, let's say, 5 enemies of the type1?, I want to be able to control the number of enemies with a variable.

Comment: Put the switch statement inside a function which takes a count as a parameter.  Then put a loop inside each case of the switch.